# Can't update Android Studio to 2.3 version

Tags: updates, android-studio, update-alternatives

I try update my android studio 2.2.3 to 2.3 on Linux 16.04. I click on check for update, update and restart. It starts to downloading patch file at the end of downloading it crashes android studio.

- How I can update my android studio?
- Is there any chance by updating android studio through terminal?

SOLVED:

Just delete old version and install new one.

Comment: My take on this was to download the new android studio from official website and import settings from the old version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update Java in your OS first by using below command

> sudo apt-get update

and

> sudo apt-get upgrade

Then your Android Studio will be fine.

Comment: That did not help